# What differential equation does this function satisfy?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Given the equation:

$$\nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x) = 0$$

for two scalar fields $f$ and $g$. It follows that when this is satisfied $h(f,g)=0$ for some function $h$. The question is to find a smooth function $h$ given functions $f$ and $g$ such $h(s,t)=0$ if and only if there exists a solution to: $s=f(x), t=g(x), \nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x) = 0$ and otherwise $h(s,t)\neq 0$.

Can we infer a differential equation that is satisfied by $h$? Or any other properties?

If we write $h$ as:

$$h(f,g) = \sum a_{nm} f^n g^m$$

is there a way to find values of $a_{nm}$ knowing the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ ?

My first attempt at trying to write a function which if it converges (which it probably doesn't) seems to have the right properties

$$ \frac{1}{h(u,v)} = \int \frac{1}{\left((u-f(x))^2+(v-g(x))^2 + |\nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x)|^2\right)^2 } dx^3 $$

Theoretically this has the right properties but I can't simplify it. e.g. whenever the top equation is satisfied the RHS becomes infinite which implies the function h is zero as required.

Comment: Why do you know such a function $h$ exists in the first place?

Comment: This is a well known fact from fluid dynamics. Also, the equation defines a 1D curve.

Comment: It's clear that an $h$ exists such that $h(f,g)=0$.  What is not at all clear is that such an $h$ can be written as the summation given in the problem.

Comment: I assume that you are in ${\mathbb R}^3$? The gradients are either parallel or zero, so $f(x)=k(x) g(x)$ where $\nabla k$ is also proportional to $\nabla f$ or $\nabla g$. Generically we could take $k$ to be any function of either $f$ or $g$. For example  $f(x)= k(g(x))g(x)$.

Comment: @mikestone Yes h(f,g) defines the points where the gradients are parallel. The points are not always parallel for any two functions f and g!

Comment: @zooby The question asks us to find the functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy the PDE. The answer is that any $h$ will do.

Comment: Nope, the question is to find and implicit function for $h$ given two functions $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that $f$ and $g$ are given and then find the points$(x,y,z)$  at which the $\nabla f\times \nabla g=0$  equation is satisfied?  If so then this is not a well-posed  problem. Generically there need be no solution ---  or the solution set could be line, two or three dimensional  region or its dimension  can change from place to place.

Comment: Nope. the equation defines a curve. each point in the line corresponds to a pair f(x), g(x). Make a graph of these values on a f,g axis. This is a curve. Find the equation of this curve h(f,g)=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53708/discussion-between-mike-stone-and-zooby).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the function $h$. The idea is that one can define the smooth map $F \, : \, \mathbb{R}^3 \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^2$ by
\begin{align}
s &= f(x)\\
t &= g(x) 
\end{align} where $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 $. The restriction $$\nabla f(x) \times \nabla g(x) = 0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ implies that the tangent map $DF(x)$ (the Jacobi 2 x 3 matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$) is singular, meaning that it is not a submersion, i.e. it is not locally surjective. Let us assume that for $x \in  U \, \subseteq \, \mathbb{R}^3$ in an open domain $U$ the gradient $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$. Then the image $F(U)$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but a one dimensional smooth curve because $\text{rank} \, DF(x) = 1$. To construct this curve, take a solution $x = x(\sigma)$, with $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$, of the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dx}{d\sigma} = \nabla f(x)$$ Then the curve in question is given by 
\begin{align}
s &= f\big(x(\sigma)\big) = s(\sigma)\\
t &= g\big(x(\sigma)\big) = t(\sigma)
\end{align} 
Indeed, when you check the derivative 
\begin{align}
\frac{ds}{d\sigma} &= \nabla f\big(x\big) \cdot \frac{dx}{d\sigma} = |\nabla f(x)| \neq 0\\
\frac{dt}{d\sigma} &= \nabla g\big(x\big) \cdot \frac{dx}{d\sigma} = (\nabla f(x) \, \cdot \, \nabla g(x))
\end{align}
This means that the function $s = s(\sigma)$ can be inverted and written as 
$\sigma = \sigma(s)$. After that, one can substitute $\sigma$ in $t = t(\sigma)$ obtaining the function $t = \phi(s) = t\big(\sigma(s)\big)$. Consequently, one can write $h(s,t)$ as 
$$h(s,t) = k\big( \phi(s) - t \big)$$ for any non-constant smooth $k(r)$ function with $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Edit.** On the one hand, the system of ODE's
$$\frac{dx}{d\sigma} = \nabla f(x)$$ is not necessarily solvable explicitly. On the other hand, however, this system is not that important, I just took it as a way of systematically obtaining a curve $x = x(\sigma)$ transverse to the level surfaces $C_s = \{x \, : \, f(x) = s\}$ for $s \in \mathbb{R}$ (or a subset of it). You might as well take $$\frac{dx}{d\sigma} = \nabla g(x)$$ or if you work locally, simply take the straight line 
$$x = x(\sigma) = x_0 + \sigma \, \nabla f(x_0)$$ which for $\sigma$ near $0$ is still transverse to the level surfaces $C_s$ near the point $x_0$ (in some cases that line could be transverse to almost all of the level surfaces). Basically, any explicit curve $x=x(\sigma)$ transverse to the level surfaces $f(x) = s$ (or transverse to the more or less the same level surfaces $g(x) = t$) will do the job. Whatever works.

Comment: I think you are a genius, sir! For the step where $\frac{dx}{d\sigma}=\nabla f(x)$. How would you write the solution. in 1 dimension it would be: $x(\sigma) = inverse \int \frac{1}{\nabla f(\sigma)} d\sigma$

Comment: @zooby we all like math don't we :)... having fun with it is what matters. Nice questions by the way. I added an edit to my post, check if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the cross product is zero, then you have 3 equations looking like $f_xg_y=f_yg_x$, with subscripts denoting partial derivatives.  So one example of a scalar $h$ is $h=f_xg_y-f_yg_x$.  To have a stronger statement, i.e. $h(f,g)=0 \implies \nabla f \times \nabla g =0$ will require a more complex $h$ or a vector-valued $h$.

Comment: You will have 3 equations but the third equation can be written in terms of the first two.

Comment: @zooby Fair enough; but you still have 2 independent equations which cannot be combined in the summation notation given in the problem.